# Customized style in Android Studio not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm creating a quiz and trying to create a consistent style for the answers. I tried to change the color of the font for the CheckBoxes but it is not changing. The size though does change.

This is what I have for the style and an example of the CheckBox specifications. When I enter android:textColor="#eeba30" into the view, the text color changes to the correct color.

```
<style name="AnswerTextStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#eeba30</item>
</style>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/q1_correct1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="question1"
    android:text="Ireland"
    android:textAppearance="@style/AnswerTextStyle"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:onClick="question1"
        android:text="Ireland" />
```

style.xml

```
         <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/customCheckBoxStyle</item>
    </style>


    <style name="customCheckBoxStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:textColor">#eeba30</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
    </style>
```

selector_checkbox

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unselected" />
    </selector>
```

OR

```
    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:onClick="question1"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textColor="#eeba30"
    android:text="Ireland" />
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to android studio... what is the selector_checkbox you are adding here? Do I add this in the xml file? If so, it is giving me a lot of errors.

Comment: create selector_checkbox xml  in  drawable folder

Comment: try last option 1st if it is not work then try 1st one